# Как рисовать в android

Tags: java, android

вводим число `n` и рисуются `n` кругов соединенные между собой как можно реализовать что-то вроде этого

[image: leader]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте для этих целей `Canvas`: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html
http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Пример круга:

```
canvas.drawCircle(mPointerX, mPointerY, mPointerSize, mTextPaint);
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую